# JavaScript - Separating the multi-value result of a field with commas

Tags: javascript

I have a field that returns multiple values exactly the following way (in multiple rows):

Field

Role1

Role2

Role3

I want to separate the resultset with commas. My end result should look like this
Role1, Role2, Role3

How do I achieve this? I have tried split, string.replace(" ",  ",") whitespace with comma, nothing works.

Thanks,

Comment: No. It is not an array

Comment: If you want to skip the first row: `str.split('\n').splice(1).join(', ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on newline and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on comma:

```
str.split('\n').join(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be syntactical error.
It should be

```
//Perfectly valid code
var Field = "Role1 \
Role2 \
Role3";
```

Then string.replace(" ", ",") should work.

Comment: That will produce a string similar to 'Role1 Role2 Role3', OP:s string had newline characters.